# ROS to control servos in R/C-Car?

Tags: control, ros, servo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i want to use BeagleBoard Black in an R/C-Car to control the steering and braking servo. Is it useful to use ROS? Or is it "too much"? Which means that this task could be solved by using standard OS like Angström or Ubuntu without having more (programming) work to do.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153661/ros-to-control-servos-in-r/c-car?/) by [ROSler93](https://answers.ros.org/users/14861/rosler93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-04-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-16**:
If you just want to control a R/C-Car, I recommend you Arduino and Processing (http://www.instructables.com/id/Processing-Controls-RC-Car-with-XBee-modules/). Actually, I also tried it. As I wanna move an autonomous robot, I use ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's perfectly doable with ROS, especially if it needs to be fully autonomous. I don't have first-hand experience running ROS on a Beaglebone, but [here's](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/HexapodRobot) a good example of a non-trivial robot using a Beaglebone and servos.

That's a pretty complicated example, so looking at its code might be a bit overwhelming. If you're completely new to ROS, I'd recommend taking it slow and going through all the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) and specifics for the [Beaglebone](http://wiki.ros.org/BeagleBone), because ROS can have a big learning curve. This [servo controller tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Servo%20Controller) might be especially helpful. It assumes you're using an Arduino, but the basic idea is the same.

---

Originally posted by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) with karma: 940 on 2015-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-05-28**:
the thing with arduino and ros is that it always have 'lost sync' issue